# Regex rewrite fix

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following 2 rewrite rules in my .htaccess file:

```
# Rule 1
RewriteRule ^(AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO)/?([a-zA-Z-]+)?/?(faq|tagged)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ /pages/seo.select-page.php?state=$1&location=$2&page=$3&title=$4 [NC,L]

# Rule 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /pages/seo.$1.php [L]
```

Overall it works fine, until my second rule needs to point to a page that starts with the same letters as rule1.

For example:

```
mydomain.co/copyright
```

in which case it defaults to:

```
mydomain.co/CO
```

I've tried adding char count but it didn't seem to work.

```
(AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO){2}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are example URLs that you want to handle with 1st rule?

Comment: Sounds like you want to add a condition to that second rule which explicitly prevents it from getting applied. Or have a try using the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag for the first rule.

Comment: @arkascha But it is the first rule that is (incorrectly) matched, not the second.

Comment: @MrWhite Oh, indeed, I missed the `NC` flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO)/?([a-zA-Z-]+)?/?(faq|tagged)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ /pages/seo.select-page.php?state=$1&location=$2&page=$3&title=$4 [NC,L]
> ```

In order to avoid the conflict with your example URL (`example.com/copyright`) you could simply remove the `NC` flag on the first rule to make it a case-sensitive match - specifically the first two uppercase characters. The 2nd and 3rd path-segments ("location" and "title") already match `a-z` and `A-Z` (so are already case-insensitive). So, this would only be an issue if `faq` or `tagged` could be requested as anything other than all lowercase.

However, this rule is rather too generic as it allows any subsequent path segment to be omitted in any order, including the slashes (path delimiters)**<sup>*1</sup>**, which would result in an invalid rewrite (as in your example).

(**<sup>*1</sup>** It is the optional delimiters that allows `/copyright` to be successfully matched.)

To allow the 2nd, 3rd and 4th path segments to be optional, but only in that order and importantly enforcing the slash delimiters, then you could adjust the regex to include a series of nested non-capturing subgroups:

```
RewriteRule ^(AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO)(?:/([a-zA-Z-]+)(?:/(faq|tagged)(?:/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?)?)?$ /pages/seo.select-page.php?state=$1&location=$2&page=$3&title=$4 [L]
```

This now only permits a URL of the form `/state` or `/state/location` or `/state/location/page` or `/state/location/page/title`. (Except that the regex for "location" and "title" are very similar - so these could potentially be reversed. And the "location" regex would also match `faq` and `tagged`.)

This would also avoid the conflict with a URL like `/copyright` with or without the `NC` flag, since the slash delimiter after the 2 character "state" code is mandatory if the "location" is present.

However, as written, this modified rule does not allow a URL that ends in a trailing slash, which your earlier rule would permit.

---

*Aside:*

> I've tried adding char count but it didn't seem to work.
>
> ```
> (AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO){2}
> ```

That isn't a "char count". `{2}` is a numeric quantifier that matches the preceding pattern exactly twice. So, in this case, it actually matches 4 uppercase characters. It is equivalent to:

```
(AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO)(?:AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO)
```

(Only the first group is capturing.)

Comment: I had a partial success with this solution. It did differentiate between /CO and /copyright but the links that included additional parameters after /CO/faq... resulted in 404 error. I think if I could set a rule that would differentiate the first segment as == 2 chars vs 3+ it may do it.

Comment: @santa "the links that included additional parameters after /CO/faq... resulted in 404 error" - can you give examples of the URLs being requested. From your rule `/CO/faq` should not be a valid request since `faq` is expected in the 3rd path segment, not the 2nd? "if I could set a rule that would differentiate the first segment as == 2 chars vs 3+ it may do it." - That's basically, what the updated rule does in my answer.

Comment: "From your rule `/CO/faq` should not be a valid request" - although in this instance `faq` will be seen as the `location`, not the `page`, which is presumably the intention.